# Android Kernel Drivers for Camera Device

Tags: android, camera, kernel, drivers, decoder

I have a problem interfacing a video decoder(tvp5150) as a camera to a android samsung dev-kit works on FIMC API.

As far as I goggled the decoders do work as camera interface for composite cameras. I added the drivers in the kernel from menuconfig , updated the board file, but when I launch the DEFAULT CAMERA application the drivers are never initialized however the device was probed successfully. 
All I can see is black screen and no vsync/hsync on chip.

My questions are

- do I need to use a custom application in user-space that opens the new camera device.
- do I need to add driver information in framework or other layers as well like kernel layer
- do I need to add configuration in ioctl functions too.
- what is `mem2mem_test_dev.c in /kernel/drivers/media/video/`  for. virtual camera test pattern? if yes how can I use it in android?
- what did I missed here i am new to kernel and clueless what else to do after adding kernel drivers

I need some help and some detailed examples if possible.

Comment: You need to clean up your question.

Comment: It is possible that you need to add a lot of functionality to interface with the driver into the android framework / somewhere in userspace. Cameras are no fun from what I heard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write/port camera HAL (libcamera) - see TI porting guide http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI-Android-DevKit-Camera_Porting_Guide

Comment: I followed this TI link and it does seems I missed a lot of stuff. One thing I have a Samsung kit and its kernel is a bit different stock kernel only use V4l2 but this kernel also incorporates FIMC modlue. Can you provide with something more related to Samsung(s5pv210) architecture. I searched a lot but there is nothing I found for that chipset.

Comment: I posted this link as an example of what you need to implement to bring up new camera module in Android. If you cannot find HAL for your driver, then you have to write it yourself.